# How to configure / troubleshoot a new keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, keyboard-layout, 16.10

I have a Toshiba Satellite P755 laptop. I just bought a new keyboard intended for a different model, but of the same physical size and therefore likely compatible, for it.

The new keyboard's connector is identical, as well the layout and indeed the keys themselves are nearly all identical save for a backlight and the associated wire, which was not present on the original.

I took the old keyboard out of my laptop and installed the new one. `xinput` detects the new keyboard just fine:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 04d9:1400                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K400                             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M510                             id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 04d9:1400                             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)] !!!
```

but it does not work in the BIOS / at boot, in my Ubuntu installation (which was configured for the old keyboard), nor in an Ubuntu Live CD (which are notorious for having every driver for everything ever).

Interestingly, in both my Ubuntu install and the Live CD, the only keys which work are these:

```
$ xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
21 equal
22 BackSpace
106 KP_Divide
63 KP_Multiply
82 KP_Subtract
79 KP_Home
80 KP_Up
81 KP_Prior
83 KP_Left
84 KP_Begin
85 KP_Right
87 KP_End
89 KP_Next
91 KP_Delete
104 KP_Enter
27 r
35 bracketright
41 f
48 apostrophe
36 Return
55 v
37 Control_L
133 Super_L
105 Control_R
```

This is good news, and I think the problem is software related, not hardware.

How can I find a driver for it, or configure / troubleshoot it manually?

Comment: Probably better to query with the vendor/manufacturer whether hardware is really compatible or not; Check the product datasheet, if any? There seem to be very less keys that worked with the newer one. Anyway, +1 for `xev` troubleshooting method.

Comment: @clearkimura You're funny for thinking Toshiba care about Linux, or release datasheets  ;)

Comment: I don't think so; I mean new keyboard against the laptop model; Product datasheet to check if the new keyboard requires to "activate" before able to configure with software (BIOS/Linux). I read that some keyboards need to follow steps to "activate" by pressing few keys on boot. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: The keyboard is likely not pin compatible to the original. You could attach a standard USB keyboard to it and still use it to some degree until you obtain the correct keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me a hardware issue because there is a pattern in those working keys, this is compared to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` layout (may be you are using other layout)

```
   .. 04 .. 11         12
AE                     equal
AD    r                bracketright
AC    f     apostrophe
AB    v
```

As you see those letters are from same column, `KP_*` are from same block and same thing for control keys.

- May be the connector is misaligned
- Or they don't have same pins map (not same order for rows and columns in the connection).

Comment: I would tend to agree with this assessment. Size is no indication of compatibility. +1 for the misalignment and pinout points.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to update ur system and usb ids?

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
update-usbids
```

Maybe this will help.

Comment: Updating USB ID's will have no effect because it's a built-in laptop keyboard, not a USB keyboard. Additionally updating USB ID's does nothing except in rare circumstances replace a blank device name with the manufacturer and model names.